# Unique id for blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp jquery file upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

When I select a file, it generate a row with collapse like that:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#video" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="video">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
    <span>Collapse It!</span>
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="video">
    <div class="well">
        ......
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I select more than files it also generate multiple collapse div block with the same id (`id="video"`). So how can I generate a unique id for each row.

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Help me, please !!!!

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: Could you share the code that generates the new row? You should append some number to the id's, such as the count of previous similar objects: `id="video" + $(".btn-info").length()`